# Why Nullable integer data columns can not combine in one block

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As shown in [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), the construction of it must be pandas.array.

And as shown in [pandas.array](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.array.html#pandas.array), it said 'It’s expected that data represents a 1-dimensional array of data.'. In that case, if i had multi columns of Nullable integer, it will all in different blocks so that they are discontinuity in memory.

Are there any way to construct continuity memory to store multi columns of Nullable integer?

If not, why pandas didn't support it?

Comment: Why do you want that in the first place? Pandas columns are *usually* intended to be manipulated individually, if that answers your second question.

Comment: Actually same type columns are stored in one block, there store memory are continued. If i use functions like DataFrame.to_numpy(), if they are in one blocks, then they didn't need to copy and merge.